# Getting multiple controls and changing propertys

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Ok so my request is a bit complicated to explain. I have a button that does the following when clicked:

```
peopleNum = 0;
topPosition = 10;
public void submitStudent(string name)
    {
        peopleNum++;
        topPosition += 25;

            ComboBox people_comboBox = new ComboBox();
            people_comboBox.Name = "people_comboBox" + peopleNum;
            //ComboBox people_label_finder = this.Controls.Find("people_comboBox" + peopleNum, true).FirstOrDefault as ComboBox;
            people_comboBox.Left = 150;
            people_comboBox.Top = topPosition;

            string[] people_comboBox_itemList = new string[3];
            people_comboBox_itemList[0] = "Present";
            people_comboBox_itemList[1] = "Late";
            people_comboBox_itemList[2] = "Absent";

            people_comboBox.DataSource = people_comboBox_itemList;
            people_comboBox.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(people_comboBox_enter);
            people_comboBox.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(people_comboBox_leave);

        this.Controls.Add(people_comboBox);
    }
```

and then for the functions of "people_comboBox_enter" and "people_comboBox_leave" here is the code:

```
private void people_comboBox_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox people_comboBox = this.Controls["people_comboBox" + peopleNum] as ComboBox;
            if (people_comboBox != null)
            {
                people_comboBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        private void people_comboBox_leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox people_comboBox = this.Controls["people_comboBox" + peopleNum] as ComboBox;
            if (people_comboBox != null)
            {
                people_comboBox.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```

What I want to happen is that so when the mouse is over a comboBox, it will turn Red and when the mouse leaves it will turn back white. What the result actually is, that when the mouse is over any of the comboBoxs (when there are multiple) only the last one gets changed. How can I accomplish this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Side note: usually people run into this when doing closures over iteration variable, but you did explicitly coded it - store last `peopleNum` in the member variable and than get surprised that it is actually the last one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother using `this.Controls`. The control that fired the event is already in `sender`.

Try this in your "enter" and "leave" events:

```
var people_comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
```

With your current approach, `peopleNum` is incremented each time you click the `submitStudent` button. So if you click it 3 times, you're basically running this code every time:

```
ComboBox people_comboBox = this.Controls["people_comboBox2"] as ComboBox;
```

Comment: +1 also it would be better with a null-check. because `sender` might be different type or null if the event handler is triggered manually.it's unlikely but possible.